# PrimeNG Calendar need to find a way to override default enter key behavior

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, calendar, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG's calendar component. For a specific scenario, I want to override the default Enter key behaviour. Currently, when the calendar is open, Enter key closes the calendar. I want to run some logic before the calendar is closed.

I've checked that on Enter key, the onClose event of the calendar is invoked.

**Things I've tried**:

Call a function on keydown event of the calendar. If the Enter key is pressed, then run my custom logic. However, the onClose event is fired before the keydown event. As such, my custom logic runs after the calendar has already closed

**Possible Solution:**

If somehow I could figure out what caused the datepicker to close, then I could run my custom logic. For example, the datepicker is closed when user clicks outside, or when Enter key is pressed (in my case).

**Further research**:

I found a github issue where the user wanted the calendar overlay to close when Enter key is pressed.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9880

On inspecting their changes, I found that in function onInputKeydown(event), they are setting the overlayVisible field of the calendar to false when Enter key is pressed. I believe this is what triggers the onClose event of the calendar. Just pointing this out incase anyone finds this helpful.

**StackBlitz**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-xbkrhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In the stackblitz, edit the date using the input field and then press Enter. On the console log window, you will find out that first, the onClose event is fired. After that, the keydown event of the calendar is fired. I want the keydown event to first first, so that I can execute some custom logic before the onClose event is fired.

**Versions:**

PrimeNG version: ^17.5.0

Angular version: ~15.2.0

Comment: Could you kindly provide a StackBlitz showcasing your use case, please?

Comment: @Mouayad_Al I have edited the post and added a StackBlitz link. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the keydown event run before onClose event here is a solution using RxJS operators:

1- Implements AfterViewInIt.

2- Inside HTML add a template reference `#calender` and read the `calender` using `@ViewChild` :

```
    <p-calendar
      #calender
      inputId="basic"
      [(ngModel)]="date"
    ></p-calendar>
```

```
  @ViewChild('calender') calender: Calendar;
```

3- inside the `ngAfterViewInIt()` do the following:

```
  // add delay to event emitter
  const onClose$ = this.calender.onClose.pipe(delay(500));

  const keyEnter$ = fromEvent(
      this.calender.inputfieldViewChild.nativeElement,
      'keydown'
    ).pipe(filter<KeyboardEvent>((e) => e.key == 'Enter'));

    merge(onClose$, keyEnter$).subscribe((res) => {
     //here you can check if the res is instanceof KeyboardEvent and do your logic
      if(res instanceof KeyboardEvent){// but your logic here}
    });
```

you can check the `StackBlitz` here:
[Order onClose event after Keydown event](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-mpfqan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)